# How to shift a column of an array one row up or down in python?

Tags: python, arrays

```
myarray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
]
```

How to move column 2 one row down, and column 3 one row up and become this?

```
myarray = [
        [1, na, 6],
        [4, 2, 9],
        [7, 5, na],
    ]
```

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: this looks like Javascript. If you want, I can help you with code in Java. Let me know.

Comment: @RileyCarney Python:)